# How to do data sorting and filtering at the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a code like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string[] searchString, string sortOrder)
    {
        
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "Price desc" : "Price";

        var cosmetics = from s in db.Cosmetics
                       select s;
        //Sorting logic
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
            case "Price":
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderBy(s => s.Price);
                break;
            case "Price desc":
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderByDescending(s => s.Price);
                break;
            default:
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                break;
        }
        //Filter data logic
        if (searchString.Length != 0)
        {
            var li = new List<Cosmetic>();

            foreach (string ss in searchString)
            {
                List<Cosmetic> ll = cosmetics.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(ss)).ToList();
               
                li.AddRange(ll);

            }
            return View(li);
        }

        return View(await cosmetics.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I want data filtering and sorting to work together. I tried to connect them, but the result was such that all products were displayed regardless of what I passed to "string [] searchString"

Update

Filter data:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
<input class="form-control col-md-8 d-inline-block align-middle" type="checkbox" name="searchString" placeholder="Find" value="A" />
<input class="form-control col-md-8 d-inline-block align-middle" type="checkbox" name="searchString" placeholder="Find" value="B" />
<input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Sorting:

```
<a class="m-1" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.NameSortParm" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter">Name</a>

<a class="m-1" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.PriceSortParm" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter">Price</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `searchString` is a string array, which can not be regonized in `asp-route-searchString`. I suggest you could receive the two searchString separately.

Filter:

```
<form id="my_form" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <input class="form-control col-md-8 d-inline-block align-middle" type="checkbox" name="searchString1" placeholder="Find" value="A" />
    <input class="form-control col-md-8 d-inline-block align-middle" type="checkbox" name="searchString2" placeholder="Find" value="B" />
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Sorting:

```
<a class="m-1" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.NameSortParm" asp-route-searchString1="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter1" asp-route-searchString2="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter2">Name</a>

<a class="m-1" asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.PriceSortParm" asp-route-searchString1="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter1" asp-route-searchString2="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter2">Price</a>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(string searchString1, string searchString2, string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter1 = searchString1;
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter2 = searchString2;
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";
    ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "Price desc" : "Price";

    //filter and sort 

}
```

**Update:**

If you have different filter conditions, I think javasript can meet it. You could get the filter and sort condition in js then append them as querstring to url manually.

I have made an example based on this, you can refer to below codes:

**Model:**

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Car>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}


<form id="my_form" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <label>Color:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="black" /><span>Black</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="white" /><span>White</span>
    <br />
    <label>Manufacturer:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer" value="A" /><span>A</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer" value="B" /><span>B</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer" value="C" /><span>C</span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer" value="D" /><span>D</span>

    <input class="btn btn-info float-right" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a class="sort" id="sortname" data-sortorder="@ViewBag.NameSortParm" href="javascript:void(0)" >@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
            </th>
            <th>
                <a class="sort" id="sortprice" data-sortorder="@ViewBag.PriceSortParm" href="javascript:void(0)" >@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        var color = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.color));
        var manufacturer = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.manufacturer));

        $(function () {
            var checkoptions = [];
            checkoptions = color.concat(manufacturer);
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if (checkoptions.includes(this.value)) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                }
            });
        })

        $(".sort").click(function () {
            var sortorder = $(this).data('sortorder');
            var link = "/Home/Index?";
            color.forEach(function (value) {
                link += "color=" + value + "&";
            });
            manufacturer.forEach(function (value) {
                link += "manufacturer=" + value + "&";
            });
            link += "sortOrder=" + sortorder;
            window.location.href = link;
        })
    </script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index(string[] color, string[] manufacturer, string sortOrder)
{
    ViewBag.color = color;
    ViewBag.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    ViewBag.NameSortParm = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "Price_desc" : "Price";

    var cars = _context.Car.ToList();
    var co_cars = new List<Car>();
    var ma_cars = new List<Car>();

    if (color.Length != 0)
    {
        foreach (string co in color)
        {
            var colorfiltercars = _context.Car.Where(c => c.Color.Contains(co)).ToList();
            co_cars.AddRange(colorfiltercars);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        co_cars = cars;
    }

    if (manufacturer.Length != 0)
    {
        foreach (string ma in manufacturer)
        {
            var manufacturerfiltercars = _context.Car.Where(c => c.Manufacturer.Contains(ma)).ToList();
            ma_cars.AddRange(manufacturerfiltercars);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ma_cars = cars;
    }

    var filtercars = co_cars.Intersect(ma_cars);

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "Name_desc":
            filtercars = filtercars.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
            break;
        case "Price":
            filtercars = filtercars.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Price));
            break;
        case "Price_desc":
            filtercars = filtercars.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Price));
            break;
        default:
            filtercars = filtercars.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
            break;
    }
       
    return View(filtercars.ToList());
}
```

**And the Datasource:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: As an example, I gave 2 checkboxes, they can be endless.
I want to make these checkboxes like filters in online stores. For example, filter by color, manufacturer, year of manufacture, and all this at the same time. Can you tell me how to do it differently?

Comment: @Betsq9 I updated my answer, have a look.

Comment: One question  `var filtercars = co_cars.Intersect(ma_cars);                               
filtercars = co_cars.Intersect(purposeFor);` Am I adding more filters correctly?

Comment: @Betsq9 You need to take the intersection on the basis of the previous one. `var filtercars = co_cars.Intersect(ma_cars);  filtercars = filtercars.Intersect(purposeFor);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it by checking if searchString is passed to your controller. Also, check the updated code to make it easier to read.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string[] searchString, string sortOrder)
    {
        
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "Price desc" : "Price";

        var cosmetics = from s in db.Cosmetics
                        select s;
     
        //Filter data logic
        if (searchString.Length != 0)
        {
          cosmetics = cometics.Where(c => searchString.Any(s => s.Contains(c.Name)));    
        }
 
        //Sorting logic
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                break;
            case "Price":
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderBy(s => s.Price);
                break;
            case "Price desc":
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderByDescending(s => s.Price);
                break;
            default:
                cosmetics = cosmetics.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                break;
        }

      return View(await cosmetics.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Comment: My code above works. I want to be able to filter the data, and sort these filtered data, for example, by price.
At the moment I can filter the data. But if I click to sort, then the filtering is reset and all products are displayed, and not the ones that I filtered.

Comment: How are you calling it from front end. Seems like you are not passing the searchString when sort is clicked.